# Получить все возможные варианты строки средствами PHP

Tags: php

Имеется строка $x.$z.$c.$v при этом переменные $x,$z,$c,$v могут принимать только значения от 0 до 5.

Другими словами нужно перебрать все комбинации от 0000 до 5555 и поместить в массив.

Пока что придумал такое решение, но оно ужасное:

```
$arr[] = '0000';
for($u=0; $u < 9999; $u++) {
    $max = rand(0,5).rand(0,5).rand(0,5).rand(0,5);

    if(!in_array($max,$arr)){
        $arr[] = $max;
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересно, чем устроил отмеченный галкой вариант? Предположим у тебя будет строка длины 11 ты будешь 11 циклов делать? В принципе чем он показался тебе хорошим? Просто интересно

Comment: Ну этот довод постоянно читаю чуть ли не на всех форумах.Если есть код, то он должен быть универсальным и на все случаи жизни. Я не оперирую большими строками кода, я не участвую в больших проектах итд. У  меня простенькие сайты. Всегда отдаю предпочтение решениям с минимум кода. Вариант с циклами меня вполне устраивает и 11 циклов я там не буду делать. Ваш вариант тоже неплох, но взгянув на него сходу и не поймешь что там творится, он больше подходит для манипуляций с айпишниками. Да и выполнятся он будет куда дольше с большими строками

Comment: На самом деле другие исполнения кода лишь нуждаются в некоторой оптимизации/рефакторинге в то время как выбранный подход в простонародии называют "говнокод". И в любой компании за это отрезают руки. А экономия на сотых секундах - роли не играют. Но дело твоё кем ты хочешь быть)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваше решение в каком-то плане правильное, но учитывая рандом на пыхе могу сказать что иногда будут получаться не все нужные вам числа.

Я думаю, так будет рациональнее:

```
$array=array();
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
for($j=0;$j<6;$j++){
for($k=0;$k<6;$k++){
for($o=0;$o<6;$o++){
$num=$i.$j.$k.$o;
array_push($array,$num);
}
}
}
}
```

1295 чисел получилось в итоге.

Comment: А если в строке будет 11 разрядов - писать 11 циклов?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский конечно, но это решение "в лоб".

Comment: мде...это жесть

Comment: а если заранее неизвестно сколько разрядов делать `if` или `switch/case` я подозреваю? :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский всё может быть, это решение именно для этой задачи, для решения других можно придумать что-нибудь другое.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getArrByStrNumber($str) {        
    $digit = str_replace('.', '', $str);
    $count = strlen($digit);
    $digit = (int) $digit;
    $maxlen = pow(10, $count);
    $result = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $digit; ++$i) {
        $result[] = ($i < $maxlen) ? str_pad($i, $count, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) : $i;
    }

    return $result;
}

// ----------------------------------------------
$inputStr = '1.2.5.1';        

echo '<pre>';
print_r(getArrByStrNumber($inputStr));
echo '</pre>';
```

Суть:

- разбиваем строку по разделителям
- подсчитываем сколько длина числа (`$count`), чтоб в дальнейшем добавлять нули в начало.
- приводим строку к числу, чтобы можно было сделать цикл
- собственно делаем цикл от 0 до значения этого числа и заносим в массив
- в массив заносим так: если значение `$i` меньше, чем самый верхний разряд, значит надо ставить нули вперед, иначе - без нулей. Всё это пихаем в массив.
- возвращаем этот самый массив

Если изначальная строка имеет вид не `1.2.5.1`, а `1251`, т.е. цифры не перечислены через точку, то в коде строки

```
$digit = str_replace('.', '', $str);
$count = strlen($digit);
$digit = (int) $digit;
```

будут иметь вид

```
$count = strlen($str);
$digit = (int) $str;
```

---

Инфа о функциях:

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)

[strlen](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strlen.php)

[str_pad](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-pad.php)

---

P.S. Уверен, что всё это можно еще получше сделать, но для начала сойдет)

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/Rz3Ckw

```
<?php

function increment($source, $target, $index) {
    if ($source[$index] == (int) $target[$index]) {
        $source[$index] = 0;
        $source = increment($source, $target, --$index);
    }
    else {
        $source[$index] += 1;
    }

    return $source;
}

$launch = '0000';
$target = '0055';

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($launch); $i ++) {
    $source[] = (int) $launch[$i];
}

while (join('', $source) <> $target) {
    $source = increment($source, $target, 3);
    echo join(' ', $source);
}
```